# Mysql how limit left join results

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

I have two tables: songs and groups

i want limit the songs are match the group to 3

i tried this:

```
SELECT
groups.`IDgroup`,
groups.`name` AS g_name,
songs.`IDsong`,
songs.`name` AS s_name
FROM  `groups` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN songs ON (groups.`IDgroup` = songs.`IDgroup` LIMIT 3)
```

Comment: What would your expected output be?

Comment: Can you elaborate more?? because i and i think more people dont understand you..

Answer (score 1):

Put the `limit` out of parentheses:

```
SELECT
groups.`IDgroup`,
groups.`name` AS g_name,
songs.`IDsong`,
songs.`name` AS s_name
FROM  `groups` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN songs 
ON groups.`IDgroup` = songs.`IDgroup` 
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: i need to limit only the left join not all query

Answer (score 1):

It is generally not a good idea to put a limit on a query that does not explicitly order its results. The reason is that it could return different results over time.

So, you may want to consider adding an

ORDER BY groups.`IDgroup`, songs.`IDsong`

to your query (before the LIMIT 3), assuming that this combination is unique.

Comment: i know that but i need to limit only the left join not all query

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
g.`IDgroup`,
g.`name` AS g_name,
s.`IDsong`,
s.`name` AS s_name
FROM  `groups` g 
LEFT OUTER JOIN songs s 
using ('idgroup')
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: this will return 3 songs in total

Answer (score 1):

This query will return the last 3 songs for each group:

```
SELECT
    c.`IDgroup`,
    c.`name` AS g_name,
    s.`IDsong`,
    s.`name` AS s_name
FROM
    groups c 
        JOIN (
            SELECT 
                IF(@C != c.IDgroup, @ROWNUM := 1, @ROWNUM := @ROWNUM +1) AS RN,
                @C := c.IDgroup,
                c.IDgroup,
                s.IDsong,
                s.name
            FROM groups c 
                LEFT JOIN songs s ON c.`IDgroup` = s.`IDgroup`
                CROSS JOIN (SELECT @C := '') t2
            ORDER BY c.IDgroup ASC
        ) s ON c.`IDgroup` = s.`IDgroup`
        JOIN JOIN (
            SELECT IDgroup, MAX(rn) AS mx
            FROM (
                SELECT 
                    IF(@C != c.IDgroup, @ROWNUM := 1, @ROWNUM := @ROWNUM +1) AS rn,
                    @C := c.IDgroup,
                    c.IDgroup
                FROM groups c 
                    LEFT JOIN songs s ON c.`IDgroup` = s.`IDgroup`
                    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @C := '') t2
                ORDER BY c.IDgroup ASC
            ) t
            GROUP BY IDgroup
        ) maxsong ON maxsong.IDgroup = c.IDgroup AND s.rn BETWEEN maxsong.mx-2 AND maxsong.mx
ORDER BY c.IDgroup ASC, s.`name` ASC
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b65c3b/1

Comment: @user1490014 you have to open a question for query optimization then :-)

Answer (score 0):

Take the LIMIT out of the parentheses:

```
SELECT
    groups.`IDgroup`,
    groups.`name` AS g_name,
    songs.`IDsong`,
    songs.`name` AS s_name
FROM  `groups` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN songs USING (`IDgroup`)
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: this will return 3 songs in total